# Display Rails Server Info in Active Admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin, dashboard

My ActiveAdmin Welcome Dashboard is looking a little empty. And I've been unable to find a way to get it to display the simple server info I'd like to see everytime I login. app/admin/dashboard.rb gives me examples for a simple greeting message and the most recent posts:

**dashboard.rb**

```
 # Here is an example of a simple dashboard with columns and panels.
    #
    # columns do
    #   column do
    #     panel "Recent Posts" do
    #       ul do
    #         Post.recent(5).map do |post|
    #           li link_to(post.title, admin_post_path(post))
    #         end
    #       end
    #     end
    #   end

    #   column do
    #     panel "Info" do
    #       para "Welcome to ActiveAdmin."
    #     end
    #   end
    # end
```

..but what I'd really like to see is a simple list of the current version of Rails, Ruby and Puma installed.

How would this be possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add something like:

```rb
columns do
  column do
    panel 'Info' do
      ul do
        li "Ruby version: #{RUBY_VERSION}"
        li "Rails version: #{Rails.version}"
        li "Puma version: #{Puma::Const::VERSION}"
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks. Do you, by any chance, know how to add the PHP version?

Comment: Hey, adding the PHP version is tricky as it's a different runtime, and it won't return the correct version if you use any env manager like [asdf-vm](https://asdf-vm.com/). What I can think of as a workaround is to expose an endpoint from the PHP service returning this info and fetch (and cache) it in rails. Another similar solution is to write it into a file that can be fetched by rails. Does any of that work for your use case?

Comment: Writing it as a file would work. But how would I retrieve the info in, say, .php_version?

Comment: I'd write the version info to the `/tmp/php_version`, for example, to avoid permission issues. Then you can add something to the admin, like `li "PHP version: #{File.read('/tmp/php_version') rescue 'unknown'}"`. Keep in mind that in a multi-server setup, you need access to the file in all instances.

Comment: It occurs to me that's still me TELLING the system what version of PHP i'm using... I actually want the system to tell me. Is there maybe a way to do this: phpversion(?string $extension = null): string|false and have that result either show up on the activeadmin dashboard?

Comment: You can also add a cron that does the job or the simplest just to run the `\`php -r phpversion()\`` (you have to wrap it into backticks) as a [command](https://rubyapi.org/3.3/o/kernel#method-i-60). This latter is less favourable, in my opinion, as it breaks the border between the services.